# How does the categorical cross entropy function work in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I wanted to implement the categorical cross entropy function in Tensorflow by hand.I did that:

```
def my_CE(y_true, y_pred):
    log_y_pred = tf.math.log(y_pred)
    element_wise = -tf.math.multiply_no_nan(x=log_y_pred, y=y_true)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(element_wise,axis=1))
```

By doing a test, I realized that I did the right thing :

```
true = np.array([[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]])
pred = np.array([[0.01, 0.99], [0.01, 0.99]])

print('Tensorflow CE : ',tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()(true, pred))
print('My CE : ',my_CE(true, pred))



*Tensorflow CE :  tf.Tensor(2.307610273361206, shape=(), dtype=float64)
My CE :  tf.Tensor(2.307610260920796, shape=(), dtype=float64)*
```

But in another test, I found that the answers were different:

```
y_true = tf.constant([[0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1.0]])
y_pred = tf.constant([[0 , 0 , 0 ,0 ,  .3]])

print('Tensorflow CE : ',tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
print('My CE : ',my_CE(y_true, y_pred).numpy())


Tensorflow CE :  1.192093e-07
My CE :  1.2039728
```

Worse, I realized that the tensorflow function did not work to my understanding!
That is, as I increased the probability that the class was correct, nothing less than the value of the tensorflow loss function

```
for i in np.arange(.1,1,0.1):
    y_true = tf.constant([[0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1.0]])
    y_pred = tf.constant([[0 , 0 , 0 ,0 ,  i]])
    print('Tensorflow CE : ',tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()(y_true, y_pred).numpy())

Tensorflow CE :  1.192093e-07
Tensorflow CE :  1.192093e-07
Tensorflow CE :  1.192093e-07
Tensorflow CE :  1.192093e-07
Tensorflow CE :  1.192093e-07
Tensorflow CE :  1.192093e-07
Tensorflow CE :  1.192093e-07
Tensorflow CE :  1.192093e-07
Tensorflow CE :  1.192093e-07
```

Comment: You can probably see the `reduction=` argument in `CategoricalCrossentropy`. See [tf.keras.losses.Reduction](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Reduction)

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal  Thanks, but I have somehow checked this issue.
  My fundamental question is why increasing or decreasing the probability of a correct class does not affect the tensorflow loss function.

Comment: You're passing a y_pred that does not sum to 1. You need to either softmax your y_pred or set `from_logits` to True. Please read the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy) before posing.

Comment: @gobrewers14 Thank you for your answer. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> You're passing a `y_pred` that does not sum to `1`. You need to either
> `softmax` your `y_pred` or set `from_logits` to `True`. For more
> information you can read
> [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy). (paraphrased from gobrewers14)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def my_CE(y_true, y_pred):
    log_y_pred = tf.math.log(y_pred)
    element_wise = -tf.math.multiply_no_nan(x=log_y_pred, y=y_true)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(element_wise,axis=1))

# y_pred sum to 1
y_true = tf.constant([[0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1.0]])
y_pred = tf.constant([[0 , 0.7 , 0 ,0 ,  .3]])

print('Tensorflow CE : ',tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
print('My CE : ',my_CE(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
```

output:

```
Tensorflow CE :  1.2039728
My CE :  1.2039728
```

```
#softmax y_pred 
y_true = tf.constant([[0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1.0]])
y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.constant([[0 , 0.0 , 0 ,0 ,  .3]]))

print('Tensorflow CE : ',tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
print('My CE : ',my_CE(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
```

Output:

```
Tensorflow CE :  1.3770702
My CE :  1.3770702
```